# Nodejs - call Rest Wcf service with Json

Tags: node.js, wcf, request

I using [request](https://github.com/request/request) lib for post data from nodejs app to rest wcf service. I do this with xml datatype, but I would use json data instead xml:

> "I don't know How write xmlns property in json data?"

```
request(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8590/Service1.svc/auth',
        body: '<RequestData xmlns="http://localhost:8590/mPlayer">\n' +
        '  <details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details>\n' +
        '</RequestData>',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'},
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `xmlbuilder`, you can create json like this

```
const xmlbuilder = require('xmlbuilder')

const req = {
    RequestData: {
        '@xmlns': 'http://localhost:8590/mPlayer',
        details: 'Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET'
    }
}

const body = xmlbuilder.create(req, { encoding: 'utf-8' }).end()

console.log(body)
```

Here is xml you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RequestData xmlns="http://localhost:8590/mPlayer"><details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details></RequestData>
```